# Reset weight paint brushes to default values?

Tags: weight-painting

Unknowingly I've been changing the default values of the Weight Painting brushes. I would like to restore the default values. Is there way to do this?
[image]

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to reset it directly but you can append another one from another (default) blend file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "append another one".

Comment: Save a newly opened blend file somewhere (so that it contains the brush), then in the file you want the brush to be reset go to the file menu, then 'append', then go to the saved file, and in the brush directory, and select the brush

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I appended the default brushes and deleted the old ones. This is not the first time I have accidentally changed default values. I guess Blender assumes you know exactly what you are doing. I made the same mistake with cloth baking presets before.

Comment: How did this happen? Did you save your startup file forgetting that you had changed the values? You should always be able to do File > Load Factory Settings to get an unmodified .blend file that you can then save and append from if things like this happen in the future.

Comment: It's not that hard for it to happen. Just create a new Blender file, select a weight paint brush. Change a setting. Save the Blend file. Next time you open the Blend file and select the brush, you get the brush that you changed, not the  brush with the default settings.